# Xamarin.Forms - Android : OnRequestPermissionsResult is never called

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, permissions, android-permissions

Under Android I need some permissions to use the Google-Map API. I use the PermissionsPlugin :

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Plugin.Permissions/

Here some code :

```
async void RequestPermissions()
{
    var status = await CrossPermissions.Current.CheckPermissionStatusAsync(Permission.Location);
    if (status != PermissionStatus.Granted)
    {
        if (await CrossPermissions.Current.ShouldShowRequestPermissionRationaleAsync(Permission.Location))
        {
            //NavigationHelper.CurrentPage.DisplayAlert("Need location", "Gunna need that location", "OK");
        }

        var results = await CrossPermissions.Current.RequestPermissionsAsync(Permission.Location);

        //Best practice to always check that the key exists
        if (results.ContainsKey(Permission.Location))
            status = results[Permission.Location];
    }
}

public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, [GeneratedEnum] Android.Content.PM.Permission[] grantResults)
{
    PermissionsImplementation.Current.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    //base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
}
```

But I also noticed that the method "OnRequestPermissionsResult" is never called, and there is no dialog that ask me for permissions !!

Also, the permissions are in the manifest file too !

Any idea to solve this ?

Comment: Have you added `CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Init(this, savedInstanceState);`  in your MainActivity?

Comment: Yes, I have CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Init(this, bunle) !!